# Advanced Calendar Service doesn't send email invitations

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I can't get the Google "Advanced Calendar" v3 API to send invitation/notification emails. It seems to ignore the sendNotifications and sendUpdates options.

I have an Apps Script which synchronizes entries in a spreadsheet with  a gcalendar. I want created/updated events to send notifications to all participants, particularly externals so the event shows up on their calendars.

```
function testPatchEvent(calendarId, eventId) {
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);
  event.attendees.push({
    email: 'test@example.com'
  });
  return Calendar.Events.patch(event, calendarId, eventId, {
    sendNotifications: true,
    sendUpdates: 'all'
  });
}

function testInsertEvent(calendarId) {
  var event = {
    summary: 'Test event',
    start: {
      date: "2019-01-05"
    },
    end: {
      date: "2019-01-05"
    },
    attendees: [
      { email: 'test@example.com' }
    ],
  };
  return Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId, {
    sendNotifications: true,
    sendUpdates: 'all'
  });
}
```

The call returns SUCCESS, but the invitation emails are not sent. Unfortunately the spec for the returned event object doesn't include the notifications setting, so I'm not sure how to validate that I'm doing it right. Seems pretty simple, though.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have seen this [issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122770338), adding this as reference.

Comment: thanks, I opened that issue report myself. :) So if there's a syntax issue there, it's here too.

Comment: @Ohthehugemanatee did resolve this?